# Python import a package in same directory

Tags: python, import, module, package

Hey I got some trouble importing a dependency to my python function.
Excuse me I am pretty new to python so here's what my directory looks like

```
├── lambda_function.py
│── package
│   ├── geopy (with other init)
│   └── __init__.py (empty)
```

and I am trying to import geopy like this but it won't find the module although I've tried it in a lot of different ways.

```
import .package.geopy.distance as geopy
```

also tried

```
from package import geopy.distance
```

This is the error I get if it is not the module not found one

```
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'package' from partially initialized module 'package' (most likely due to a circular import) (/var/task/package/__init__.py)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}
```

Comment: Check if this can be helpful: https://www.fir3net.com/Programming/Python/how-do-you-import-a-python-module-from-another-folder.html

Comment: Where are you trying to import? Inside `lambda_function.py` ?

Comment: @DineshKumar Yes sorry I forgot to mention the import is inside lambda_function.py that's right.

Comment: Ok.You have missed `__init__.py` inside the package folder.Kindly add it and then try `from package import geopy.distance`

Comment: @Chris Ok.I see the init file after the edit. Could you please paste the error stack trace? I tried executing  and the import just works fine

Comment: @DineshKumar Of course I edited the Question above

Comment: @Chris Ah I see. The error says that there could be a circular import. By any chance, are you importing `lambda_function.py` into `geopy`  and again `geopy` into `lambda_function`? Or a similar situation elsewhere? Also what do you mean by `with other init` near geopy